# Putting text from JTextField to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

I 'm working on code that takes a string from a `JTextField` and puts it on a `JLabel`.

But my problem is always the string shown is missing the last character.

```
 private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)     {
      String  ch=jTextField1.getText();
      jLabel1.setText(ch);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just sloved : I copy the code in jTextField1KeyReleased() method , and it 100% work.Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to [use a DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to check for changes in the jTextField. Not only will that notify you *after* the changes of the additional character are incorporated, but you will also be notified about changes unrelated to keyboard events (e.g. pasting text).

Comment: Yep, 1+. Definitely you want to avoid using KeyListeners with text components.